# Unable to display GIF and PNG/JPG on QLabel

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, gif, qlabel

I can't solve one problem. I've seen solutions to this problem that looked something like this, but it doesn't work for me.  In addition, specifying the full path does not change the situation. What could be the problem? I am attaching the code below

**upd:** I understood what the problem was. QImageReader.supportedimageformats() shows that only "bmp", "pbm", "pgm", "png", "ppm", "xbm", "xpm" formats are supported. *How can I correctly add "gif" and "jpg" to the supported formats?*

**UPD:** *I solved the problem! It was only necessary to copy the folder "imageformats" to the folder with the executable file "python.exe".*

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtGui import QMovie
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(600, 400)
        self.for_gif = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.for_gif.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 40, 580, 341))
        self.for_gif.setText("")
        self.for_gif.setObjectName("for_gif")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))


class MyWidget(QMainWindow, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.movie = QMovie(self)
        self.add_gif()

    def add_gif(self):
        self.movie.setFileName("south_park.gif")
        self.for_gif.setMovie(self.movie)
        self.movie.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MyWidget()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: `QMovie` provides an error signal `https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmovie.html#error`, it's not a good idea to ignore it.

Comment: You can also use https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmovie.html#isValid before starting the movie.

Comment: I checked your code with a GIF (taken from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIF)) and it works, so you should ensure that the file is actually a GIF, it's not corrupted and the path is correct. The `error` signal noted above is a good place to start with. Besides that (and unrelated to the issue), you should not modify pyuic generated files, read how to properly use them on [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html). Finally, please be more precise with the title of your questions: the term "upload" is inappropriate for what you're doing.

Comment: I do not reproduce the error so you could have 2 errors: 1. the filename is incorrect, use the fullpath, 2. The plugin does not load, execute the script:  `QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1 python main.py`

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer, I did the necessary operations and received "Invalid device" from QMovie.lastErrorString, but I don't understand how to fix it. I also apologize for the incorrect wording, my English is bad and I'm working on it.

Comment: @BoggyDoggyBoo This message probably indicates the .gif is corrupted. Please use `@username`

Comment: @eyllanesc I used the full path with os.path.abspath, but it still doesn't work. apparently, the problem is really with the lack of a plugin, but after searching for information on the web, I came across the following method: adding a file "qgif4.dll " to the folder with gifs, but that didn't help either

Comment: @BoggyDoggyBoo The dll should be named qgif.dll, qgif4.dll is for Qt4. How have you installed PyQt5? On the other hand, it executes `set QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1` and `python main.py` in CMD and shows the log that is shown in the console.

Comment: @eyllanesc I had problems installing via the console so I downloaded from [here](https://pypi.org/project/PyQt5/)

Comment: @BoggyDoggyBoo You must install pyqt5 by executing `python -m pip install pyqt5` from the CMD

Comment: @eyllanesc I removed PyQt5 and reinstalled it from the CMD. You mentioned using "QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1 python main.py ", could you please explain where to enter it? There's still a lot I don't know

Comment: @BoggyDoggyBoo that's just a command line. Open your terminal or prompt in the folder of your script and run it.

Comment: @musicamante Thanks for the clarification, I get "QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS" is not an internal or external command, executable program or batch file.

Comment: @BoggyDoggyBoo if you're on Windows, use the commands beginning with `set` as shown above; also read how environmental variables work on your OS.

Comment: @BoggyDoggyBoo what is the output of `python -c "from pathlib import Path;from PyQt5.QtCore import QLibraryInfo;image_plugin_path = Path(QLibraryInfo.location(QLibraryInfo.PluginsPath)) / 'imageformats';print([f.name for f in image_plugin_path.glob('**/*') if f.is_file])"`?

Comment: @eyllanesc I got [] on the CMD

Comment: Maybe in windows it is in a different folder, run `python -c "from pathlib import Path;from PyQt5.QtCore import QLibraryInfo;image_plugin_path = Path(QLibraryInfo.location(QLibraryInfo.PluginsPath)) / 'imageformats';print(image_plugin_path)` and check what files are in the folder that is printed with the previous command

Comment: @eyllanesc I got "C:\Users\Åâà\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt5\plugins\imageformats". My username is not written in English, and Windows perceives it as "Åâà". Can the program break because of this?

Comment: I don't know, but more or less you can deduce the directory, check that folder and point out that there are dlls

Comment: @eyllanesc I did this and attached a screenshot of it to the post. As far as I can tell, there's everything the program needs, but it still doesn't work